# Whats stopping C# compiler from implementing 'Switch' statement on 'Type'?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-optimization

I understand that C# compiler as it stands does not let switching on Type like

```
switch (typeof(MyObj))
    case Type1:
    case Type2:
    case Type3:
```

There are solutions where a Dictionary of Type and Action could be used or a static class ([link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/05/16/switching-on-types.aspx)), but I am just curious, why is this a bad practice or not implemented in the compiler yet ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478464/c-sharp-switch-on-type?rq=1

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905/c-sharp-switch-statement-limitations-why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about primitive types you can do switch over `TypeCode`.

```
var typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(type);    
switch (typeCode)
{
    case TypeCode.Empty:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Object:
        break;
    case TypeCode.DBNull:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Boolean:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Char:
        break;
    case TypeCode.SByte:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Byte:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Int16:
        break;
    case TypeCode.UInt16:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Int32:
        break;
    case TypeCode.UInt32:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Int64:
        break;
    case TypeCode.UInt64:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Single:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Double:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Decimal:
        break;
    case TypeCode.DateTime:
        break;
    case TypeCode.String:
        break;
}
```

BTW answer for your question you may need to read [How many Microsoft employees does it take to change a lightbulb?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/28/53298.aspx)

Comment: Did not know that before thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would refer you to the accepted answer for : [switch statement in C# and "a constant value is expected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466565/switch-stmt-in-c-sharp-and-a-constant-value-is-expected) . The compiler needs to know at compile time that there won't be any duplicates, so it accepts only constants. By the way, you can achieve the same effect with

```
switch (typeof(MyObj).FullName
```

and use the names of each type as case conditions, like:

```
case "MyNamespace.Type1":
   /*stuff*/
   break;
case "MyNamespace.Type2":
   /*other stuff*/
   break;
default:
   /*default stuff*/
```

Comment: Types certainly get evaluated at compile time.

Comment: They are analyzed at compile time, but they are not compile-time _constants_.  They are re-bound at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

When would you use switching on type?  Most of the cases I can think of are better solved with inheritance, i.e. rather than doing:

```
switch (typeof(MyObj)) {
    case Type1: doSomethingForType1; break;
    case Type2: doSomethingForType2; break;
    case Type3: doSomethingForType3; break;
```

You would set it up in a much more object-oriented manner:

```
Interface ISpecialType {
    void doSomething();
}
Type1 : ISpecialType {
    doSomething() {}
}
Type2 : ISpecialType {
    doSomething() {}
}
Type3 : ISpecialType {
    doSomething() {}
}
```

then, no matter what, you just call `MyObj.doSomething();`  It's a little bit more typing at the start, but a lot more robust.

Also, if it's really important to you to switch on, you can always use typeof(MyObj).toString() and switch on that.  It's not recommended practice, since you're then hard-coding strings that are allowed to change into your switch, but you can do it.

Comment: I can what you are saying Scott and I cannot agree more, I was trying to refactor legacy code where diffirent exceptions where thrown and was caught in the parent level, which was then used for sending the apporpiate error message. And I found lots of :            if (ex is XmlSchemaValidationException)
                errorCode = ServiceExceptionErrorCode.XmlSchemaValidation;
            else if (ex is BadRequestException)
                errorCode = ServiceExceptionErrorCode.BadRequest; and was not sure how to clean this mess, to be honest. Thanks a lot for your comment anyway.