# Re factoring a collection of IF statements that hold two arguments

Tags: c#, refactoring

At the moment I have seven if statements that resemble the following code:

```
if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Colour1" && start_time > look_at_time)
{
    new_colour1.ChangeObjectMaterialColour(hit.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color);

   var colums = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("column");
   foreach( GameObject c in colums)
    c.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[1].color = new_colour1.orignalMaterial;
}


else if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Colour2" && start_time > look_at_time)
{
    new_colour2.ChangeObjectMaterialColour(hit.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color);
    var colums = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("column");
    foreach( GameObject c in colums)
       c.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[1].color = new_colour2.orignalMaterial;
}
```

Each statement is roughly 6 lines of code and takes up a lot of space and can be a little tricky to read. What I'm wanting to do is find a way to re factor this so that my code is little less clunky and doesn't take up too much space.

I had thought about changing my collection of if statements into a switch statement but I discovered that switch statements can't handle two arguments like I have above. If there any other way I can re factor my code but keep the same functionality or am I stuck with my collection of if statements?

*edit*

Updated to contain two of my 7 statements. 
Please note, I am trying to reduce the amount of IF statements I have, or find a more clever way to do them. I don't want to add any more extra lines of code or if statements.

Comment: I think asking this question here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ will be better

Comment: Show us more... there's not a lot to work with here.

Comment: As I said, it is literally 7 of the above IF statements but I'll edit my post and also cross post to code review (thank you for that, didn't know there was one!)

Comment: For future reference, after posting your second if statement it's obvious they are not identical, and therefor it was important to know the differences.

Comment: Yeah, you're correct. Should have put up more than a single omitted if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for updating your code, now we can start looking at what is duplicated.  For example, the only difference between the two blocks of code is the string `"Color1"` and `"Color2"` in the if statement, and the variable `new_colour1` which is replaced with `new_colour2`.

From here I'd suggest something like the following:

```
//This should be declared once - e.g. class level not method level.
var colorDict = new Dictionary<string, [new_color_type]> 
                    {{"Colour1", new_colour1}, {"Colour2", new_colour2}};

[new_color_type] newColor;
if(start_time > look_at_time && colorDict.TryGetValue(
        hit.collider.gameObject.tag,
        out newColor))
{
   newColor.ChangeObjectMaterialColour(
                            hit.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color);

   var colums = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("column");
   foreach( GameObject c in colums)
      c.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[1].color =
                                                    newColor.orignalMaterial;
}
```

Comment: why use a `Dictionary` instead of a `switch`?

Comment: @Jodrell, write a version using a switch statement and compare the code :)  My guess was that the Dictionary would be cleaner, shorter and simpler.

Comment: I did, http://stackoverflow.com/a/19585269/659190. Its my assertion that the `switch` shows obvious intent and will offer improved runtime performance. Whilst its possible to use the `Dictionary` save some typing this brevity doesn't translate to performance or readability.

Comment: @Jodrell, as noted on your answer you have introduced a bug, as well as wrote unclean code by deciding to use the switch.  I will remove my -1 when you fix it, but I think I've made my point.

Comment: If your point was, there are bugs in my code then yes, you made it. I hope I've fixed those now. If your point was, `Dictionary` is an inherently better approach than a `switch` statement, then we disagree. I appreciate the utility of `TryGetValue` but if the tag values are known at compile time, it makes sense to build them into the byte code, this must have benefits.

Comment: @Jodrell my point was that switch isn't always the best choice - in this case because *developers stuff it up* - it took you half an hour and three edits to end up with a version of code that's *still* more complicated, longer, and more fragile.  For example, why do you have to maintain a boolean flag telling you that no option was met?  By using a dictionary I didn't:  Forget to put in a break.  Forget to take care of default.  Accidently write non-functionally identical code.  Duplicate logic with  `new_colour1` and  `new_colour2` when `newColour` would have worked just fine.

Comment: After reasearching here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334087/net-switch-vs-dictionary-for-string-keys/1336112#1336112, I deleteing my answer, since this is a `string` lookup.

Comment: @Jodrell - thank you :)  But I'd point out that performance was never an issue and yes I'm a game developer that uses this particular game engine (this is unity code) in commercially released titles - so it's something I'm keenly aware of.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly think that the most readable and maintainable in your case is simply to move the logic in those if blocks into functions:

```
  if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Colour1" && start_time > look_at_time)
    {
        DoTheThing(new_colour1);
    }
if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Colour2" && start_time > look_at_time)
    {
        DoTheThing(new_colour2);
    }
//and so on



 void DoTheThing(MyType newColour)
  {
 newColour.ChangeObjectMaterialColour(hit.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color);
      var colums = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("column");
       foreach( GameObject c in colums)
        c.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[1].color = newColour.orignalMaterial;
    }
```

As to using `switch` you can of course do something like this:

```
switch(hit.collider.gameObject.tag)
{
  case "Colour1":
      if (start_time>look_at_time)
      {
        //do something
      }
      else if (start_time<look_at_time)
      {
        //something else
      }
      else
      {
         //they are equal, etc, etc
      }
    break;
case "Colour2":
  //and so on
}
```

or if all of the if blocks make the same comparison between `start_time` and `look_at_time` then you could invert it:

```
enum TimeDifference
{
   LessThan,Equal,GreaterThan
}
//just one way to get a constant switchable value, not necessarily the best
var diff = TimeDifference.Equal;
if (start_time>look_at_time) {diff=TimeDifference.LessThan}
else if (start_time<look_at_time) {diff=TimeDifference.GreaterThan}

switch(diff)
{
  case TimeDifference.LessThan:
     switch(hit.collider.gameObject.tag)
     {
       case "Colour1":
         //do something for Colour1
        break;   
        case "Colour2":
         //do something for Colour2
        break;
      }//end switch Colour
     break;
  case TimeDifference.GreaterThan
    switch(hit.collider.gameObject.tag)
     {
       case "Colour1":
         //do something for Colour1
        break;   
        case "Colour2":
         //do something for Colour2
        break;
      }//end switch Colour
     break;  
   default:
    //nested switch for Colour in the == case, you get the idea.
}
```

although the readbility of the either of the above versus several nicely formatted and separate `if` blocks is very debatable.

Another approach is to use a `Dictionary<string,Action<int,int>>`: (assuming`start_time` and `look_at_time` are both `int`s AND all of your logic involves them somehow)

```
var Actions = new Dictionary<string,Action<int,int>>();
Actions.Add("Colour1",(s,l)=>{
 if (start_time>look_at_time)
          {
            //do something
          }
          else if (start_time<look_at_time)
          {
            //something else
          }
          else
          {
             //they are equal, etc, etc
          }

});
```

and then your main code becomes 1 line:

```
Actions[hit.collider.gameObject.tag](start_time,look_at_time);
```

And I am sure that there are many many more ways you can rearrange that code.