# Compare strings in C# in switch-case block with different casing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a set of switch-case statements, such as "Hello, how are you", "Hi, how can I help you?". If the input from the user is verbatim i.e: "Hello, how are you", the match works.

But if the user entered "Hello, How are You", the match fails.

I would like if the user's input is the same but different casing then it should match. i.e.

```
"Hello, how are you" == "Hello, How are You" == "HELLO, how are YOU"
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: `switch` would likely be the wrong tool for the job. 

However you could always just ToLower() the strings. Though i feel the next question would be, how do i deal with extra spaces or punctuation

Comment: I cannot lowercase the switch statements because they are shown elsewhere on the UI and hence casing should be maintained.

Comment: The ToLower() will be applied only for comparison. It won't modify the string to be displayed.

Comment: If you `switch (yourValue.ToLower())`, nothing outside the switch is impacted by the ToLower - that doesn't necessarily make it a good approach though; I'm just saying that "because they are shown elsewhere on the UI" is irrelevant

Comment: Take a look at my answer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334134/how-to-make-the-c-sharp-switch-statement-use-ignorecase/51794712#51794712

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13965429/34092

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `C# 7.0` or newer then you can use [`Pattern Matching`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements) with `switch..case` like below.

```
string a = "Hello, How are You";

switch (a)
{
    case string str when str.Equals("hello, how are you", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase):
        // Your code
        break;
    default:
        // default code
        break;

}
```

Comment: The `case string` type check is redundant because it already knows `a` is a string, so you can say `case {}` (not null) instead if you want. I don't know if the compiler optimizes the secondary check away. Hopefully C# gets something like `case _ str when...` at some point when the type is already known.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `ToLower` on everything to do a non-case sensitive switch:

```
switch (myString.ToLower())
{
    case "hello, how are you":
        // do something
        break;
}
```

Comment: This is not an allocation-friendly way of comparing strings

Answer (score 2):

The `switch` handler in C# for strings is limited to exact character matching. Ultimately there are three approaches here:

- use `if`, not a `switch`, and make use of manual string equality tests - perhaps specifying a `StringComparison` for case insensitivity
- create a dictionary (perhaps static) with a case insensitive key comparer; put your expected strings in the dictionary - perhaps mapping to a private enum output, then switch on that output
- use `ToLower[Invariant]` in the switch operand, and just eat the allocation

If it isn't high throughput, the last is probably fine

Comment: @Karan well, yes, but a `switch` expression that uses `when` for every meaningful test is really no different to a series of `if`, `else` tests - just shoe-horned into the `switch` syntax for the sake of it...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting both strings to upper case or lower case and then comparing, you should use an equality comparison which can be made case-insensitive. For example:

```
String string1 = "Hello, how are you";
if (string1.Equals("Hello HOW are you", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
     ...
}
You should consider carefully exactly which rules are appropriate - ordinal, the current culture, the invariant culture, or possibly another culture entirely (e.g. using StringComparer.Create(culture, true)).
```