# Optimization: Is the order of cases in a switch statement important?

Tags: java, c#, c++, c, switch-statement

Consider a `switch` statement in your language of choice (e.g., Java, C, C#...). Of course, the order of `case` statements is important if there are fallthroughs, but assume that each `case` has a `break`, so the order is of no semantic importance.

Is the order of `case` statements important when, for example, considering optimizations? Is it better to sort the cases in ascending order or are there no benefits in any ordering? What optimizations might a compiler perform that might depend on order of `case`s. Since any compiler might or might not pick such optimizations, I do not want to ask for a specific language or compiler here. The question is about what could possibly happen.

Comment: Is this language agnostic of it is for a specific set of programming languages?

Comment: Please choose a language, because your assumption could very well be wrong.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: If my assumption is wrong, then answer for the languages you know

Comment: If memory serves for Java at least this will depend on the number/type of cases you have, and it's *possible* cache misses could play into this as well...

Comment: I won't dupe-hammer this, but this is a possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815983/does-the-order-of-case-in-switch-statement-can-vary-the-performance

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: It is a general question. If it depends on the language, then it would be interesting what holds for which language.

Comment: If that's the case, I doubt there's a single answer that can hold it for all programming languages. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Well, then use the most common ones, let's say top ten TIOBE index. Of course, I don't care about esotheric stuff, I just want to be safe in all languages that are currently of major use.

Comment: `"If my assumption is wrong, then answer for the languages you know"` -- Then your question may very well be too broad.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Okay, I picked 4

Comment: Now, have you searched the answer for any of these languages before posting the question?

Comment: As far as I know none of the languages you mentioned mandate the performance behavior of switch - so it's really a question about implementation, not languages. If you want to limit your question, it should be something like "gcc, clang, openjdk, MS CLR".

Comment: @Oak: amen, which is why Java would be so hard to answer, since only few would know the inner workings of the optimizing JVM. Again, it's too broad.

Comment: @Oak: I thought that there would be a general pattern how a switch is compiled. I did not think that all the languages/compilers would be *that* different.

Comment: @Oak that should be an answer (and a more reason to vote this as too broad).

Comment: @gexicide and I think it's a decent question, but the way to phrased it makes it just too broad. If you care about how optimizing switches work, maybe it's the compiler side you should care about, not languages. Maybe rephrase this question (or re-ask, seeing the amount of close/down votes you get here) to focus about that - e.g. "does the order of cases affect possible compiler optimization of switches". There are a few non-trivial tricks done by compilers to optimize switches, so it can be a very interesting, though maybe less practical, question.

Comment: @Oak: Basically, that was what I wanted to ask. Dunno why I was unable to articulate myself. Of course, I am interested in what a compiler will/can/might do that affects performance, and since any compiler might do this, the language should be of no importance.

Comment: I think it's a reasonable question, and not too broad, because I think from a practical standpoint there's an answer that's correct in most cases:  putting the most common cases first won't hurt, and might help, if the switch statement is a performance sink.  It does look like it might be a dupe of the question Mystical found, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on not only the language, but the compiler, and even on which compiler settings you choose.  I've seen it differ in C++ depending on which gcc optimization settings I chose.

This is because the compiler may choose to implement the switch statement as a series of tests, just like a series of if / else if statements, or it may choose to implement the switch statement as a jump table.  The series of tests will be faster for earlier tests, while the jump table will typically be equally fast irrespective of the order.

If your compiler is implementing your switch statement as a series of tests - and does not reorder them - putting the more likely cases earlier will result in faster code.  As far as I know, putting the more likely cases earlier should not normally result in slower code, so if your code spends a lot of time executing this switch statement, it can't hurt to put the more common cases earlier.

However, if you haven't profiled your code and you don't know for a fact that the switch statement is a performance problem, it's better to write the switch statement using the order that's clearest for a human being reading the code.

Comment: Also, if the switch case is really, really long so that you start getting instruction cache misses, putting the most likely cases first will lead to a speedup even in the jump table case.

Answer (score 1):

Judging on this benchmark it does matter:
http://pastebin.com/rJMEunAT

The first method finished at 0.2423 ticks, the second at 0.1654

Answer (score 1):

For languages which prohibit multiple case clauses matching, and which have compilers with at least some optimization, it almost certainly won't make a difference which order you write the case  clauses.

There are three popular ways of compiling switch statements:

- hard-coded binary search
- indexed jump table
- hashed jump table

All three require the compiler to reorder the clauses. Which one will be chosen depends on the language, the target processor, the distribution of values in the case clauses, and possibly the phase of the moon.