# Constant arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm starting learning C# a couple days, sr if it's stupid question!
I had a string array like this

```
private readonly string[] algorithm_list = {
                                              "Genetic Algorithm",
                                              "Dynamic Algorithm"
                                          };
```

and my code

```
switch (al_choose)
            {
                case algorithm_list[0]:
                    break;
                case algorithm_list[1]:
                    break;
                default:

            }
```

The error is algorithm_list[0] is not a constant! So I try other declaration like

```
private readonly string[] algorithm_list
```

or

```
private contant string[] algorithm_list
```

But it still doesn't work????
So, any suggestion for me? thanks so much!

Comment: Duplicate: [switch case in c# - a constant value is expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593377/switch-case-in-c-sharp-a-constant-value-is-expected)

Comment: no, it's different, because I want to make this to a list item in view, and also use it again in code behind, so, this is the thing I considered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For these cases, its better to use [Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
public enum AlgorithmList
{
        GeneticAlgorithm,
        DynamicAlgorithm
}
```

Then:

```
switch (al_choose)
{
    case AlgorithmList.GeneticAlgorithm:
        break;
    case AlgorithmList.DynamicAlgorithm:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

**EDIT** If you are going to bind the values of the `Enum` to a `ComboBox` you can do it this way:

```
yourCombobox.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(AlgorithmList)).Cast<AlgorithmList>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still has a problem here, I had a combo box in view, this load Algorithm List as an item list, and it didn't accept enum type.

Answer (score 4):

Array elements are not constants so you can't use array elements in switch statement.

Options:

- replace usage of array elements with inline constant `case "Genetic Algorithm":...` or actual constant values `const string Choice1="Genetic Algorithm";... case  Choice1:...`
- use sequence of `if` statements:  `if (al_choose == algorithm_list[0]) { /*do something*/ }`
- standard approach for such `switch` statement is dictionary of "choice" to "Action delegate", but I'd not jump into that.