# Is it possible to invoke a method within a switch statement?

Tags: c#

Simple question. Is it possible to invoke a method within a `switch` statement in C#? Asking for .NET >= 4.5

```
var x = "Hello World";
switch(x)
{
    case "Foo":
        break;
    // What I actually want to do
    case x.StartsWith("Hello"):
        return "Bar";
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593377/switch-case-in-c-sharp-a-constant-value-is-expected/

Comment: There are probably better ways to accomplish this. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @TravisJ You are right - I just was curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. `case` has to be followed by compile time constant, and method call is definitely not one of them.

Part of C# grammar from C# spec:

```
switch-statement:
    switch   (   expression   )   switch-block

switch-block:
{   switch-sectionsopt   }

switch-sections:
    switch-section
    switch-sections   switch-section

switch-section:
    switch-labels   statement-list

switch-labels:
    switch-label
    switch-labels   switch-label

switch-label:
    case   constant-expression   :
    default   :
```

As you can see, `case` has to be followed by *`constant-expression`*, which is described as

> A *`constant-expression`* is an expression that can be fully evaluated at
>   compile-time.