# Type Not Found In Class When Inside Switch

Tags: c#, class, types, enums, switch-statement

I'm using a `class` like an `enum` because my entries need a custom string representation:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyProject
{
    internal class Food
    {
        private string _value = "";

        private Food(string value)
        {
            _value = value;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _value;
        }

        internal static Food RedApple = new Food("red_apple");
        internal static Food YellowBanana = new Food("yellow_banana");
        internal static Food GreenMango = new Food("green_mango");
    }
}
```

I can use the `static` fields like `Food.RedApple` just fine:

```
if (str == Food.RedApple.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("apple");
else if (str == Food.YellowBanana.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("banana");
else if (str == Food.GreenMango.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("mango");
else
    Console.WriteLine("unknown");
```

However, when I use them inside `switch` statements like so:

```
using System;

namespace MyProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "red_apple";

            switch (str)
            {
                case Food.RedApple.ToString():
                    Console.WriteLine("apple");
                    break;
                case Food.YellowBanana.ToString():
                    Console.WriteLine("banana");
                    break;
                case Food.GreenMango.ToString():
                    Console.WriteLine("mango");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("unknown");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> The type name `RedApple` does not exist in the type `Food` [MyProject]

What exactly is going on here, and does this mean that I can't use my class inside `switch` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started from c# 7.0 switch statement has become more powerful and covers a lot of scenarios.

But to answer your question in shortest way you need to put a constant value in your case field. You can try putting a variable or another string property from Food inside switch statement, but it won't work either because switch is looking for a constant value.

You can look at the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) on switch statement.

Comment: I see... So C# `switch` statements need constant values. Welp, that clarifies everything. Thanks a lot for answering!

Comment: Exactly, from c# 7.0 it has got more powerful, for example you can check against a type, but in general it requires a constant value

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure what exactly your case is, but in my case(using your code), i'm getting 'CS0150 A constant value is expected.' error message here.

the problem has been answered here: [Switch case in C# - a constant value is expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593377/switch-case-in-c-sharp-a-constant-value-is-expected)

you might have a look at it first, it may be of some help.

Comment: Many thanks for the info! I like both answers, but could only choose one so I chose @SZT's because it's much closer to the issue. Thanks again for helping!