# Switch with ToLower() causes error CS0426 The type name '' does not exist in the type ''

Tags: c#

Why does the compiler only complain when a method is called in a switch statement for a constant value and why is it the error `The type name 'A' does not exist in the type`?

> CS0426 The type name 'A' does not exist in the type
>   'ClassificationIdentifiers.ClassificationIdentifiersChildren'

```
public static class ClassificationIdentifiers
{
    public static class ClassificationIdentifiersChildren
    {
        public const string A = "A";
    }
}

switch (classificationFileType)
{
    case ClassificationIdentifiers.ClassificationIdentifiersChildren.A:
        classification = ClassificationIdentifiers.ClassificationIdentifiersChildren.A;
        break;
}

switch (classificationFileType)
{
    case ClassificationIdentifiers.ClassificationIdentifiersChildren.A.ToLower():
        classification = ClassificationIdentifiers.ClassificationIdentifiersChildren.A;
        break;
}
```

[image]

I assume it has something to do with the errors below, `"A".ToLower();` or `case a.ToLower():`.

```
const string a = "A".ToLower();

switch (classificationFileType)
{
    case a.ToLower():
        classification = ClassificationIdentifiers.ClassificationIdentifiersChildren.A;
        break;
}
```

> CS0133    The expression being assigned to 'a' must be constant
>
> CS0118    'a' is a variable but is used like a type

[image]

Comment: There are a number of bits of code there. Which bit do you want explained? As an example `const string a = "A".ToLower();` - well, the error on it is pretty clear.

Comment: I suspect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593377/switch-case-in-c-sharp-a-constant-value-is-expectedis what you are interested in? Or consider using `if` rather than `switch`. Or consider using a case insensitive `Dictionary` to allow mapping from one value to another.

Comment: String cases must be constant strings, so adding `.ToLower()` is a compiler error. The fact that it complains that "The type name 'A' does not exist in the type 'ClassificationIdentifiers.ClassificationIdentifiersChildren'", rather than complaining that "A constant value is expected" looks like a minor compiler bug

Comment: I suspect CS0426 is effectively a variant of CS0118. Since the thing you want is a constant, it knows that everything prior to the last `.` would need to be a type for that to be even possible. Which seems confusing to you, if you don't know it needs a constant, but likely makes sense from the compiler's point of view.

Comment: (I asked [on the csharplang gitter](https://gitter.im/dotnet/csharplang?at=5edf5b4030401c1f2445736c))

Comment: @mjwills The question I'm interested in is: `Why does the compiler only complain when a method is called in a switch statement for a constant value and why is it the error The type name 'A' does not exist in the type`. I think @canton7 is correct but it would be nice with an answer with a link to documentation that explains why this particular error is shown.

Comment: It complains for the same reason that CS0118 occurs - because it isn't a constant. And it likely _knows_ it isn't a constant since the thing before the last `.` isn't a type.

Comment: @mjwills Yes I think so too but then I would expect `CS0150 A constant value is expected`.

Comment: Why does it matter to you? I am not _defending_ it - just hypothesizing an explanation for it. The error (from the compiler's standpoint) makes sense in the same way that CS0118 makes sense.

Comment: @mjwills True but I like to say it anyway, I hope they will write a comment some day. :) It matters because I'm interested and would like to know why the compiler throws this error and not something more obvious like `CS0150`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question can be simplified to the following:

```
public class Test
{
    public const string C = "C";  
    public void M(string s)
    {
        switch (s)
        {
            case C.ToLower():
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'C' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The thing in the `case` label is a [pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#pattern-matching-with-the-switch-statement), which can be either a constant pattern or a recursive pattern. Constant patterns are things like `1`, `"test"`, or the name of a const variable or field.

[Recursive patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns) get complex, but this one's looking for a `ToLower` type in a namespace `C`, which has an empty deconstructor. Something like:

```
public class Test
{
    public void M(object s)
    {
        switch (s)
        {
            case C.ToLower():
                break;
        }
    }
}

namespace C
{
    public class ToLower
    {
         public void Deconstruct() { }   
    }
}
```

This is why it's complaining about being unable to find a type or namespace `C`: it's looking for a `ToLower` type.

---

I think the fact that this works is just a quirk of the spec -- I can't see any useful need for it.