# C# "A constant value is expected" when trying to compare two integers in switch case

Tags: c#, switch-statement

```
int int1 = 1;
int int2 = 2;
switch(int1)
{
   case int2:
      doSomething();
      break;
}
```

Here's an example of when I get this error, is there a way to do something like that without getting the "CS0150: A constant value is expected" error, or do I have to use if statements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch case in C# - a constant value is expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593377/switch-case-in-c-sharp-a-constant-value-is-expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use an `if` statement to accomplish what you want, or make `int2` `const`.

Tutorials Point [does a good job](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/switch_statement_in_csharp.htm) of explaining this:

> The following rules apply to a switch statement −
>
> The expression used in a switch statement must have an integral or enumerated type, or be of a class type in which the class has a single conversion function to an integral or enumerated type.
>
> You can have any number of case statements within a switch. Each case is followed by the value to be compared to and a colon.
>
> The constant-expression for a case must be the same data type as the variable in the switch, and it must be a constant or a literal.
>
> When the variable being switched on is equal to a case, the statements following that case will execute until a break statement is reached.
>
> When a break statement is reached, the switch terminates, and the flow of control jumps to the next line following the switch statement.
>
> Not every case needs to contain a break. If no break appears, then it will raise a compile time error.
>
> A switch statement can have an optional default case, which must appear at the end of the switch. The default case can be used for performing a task when none of the cases is true.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `case 2`, not `case int2`. case should have a constant value not a variable.