# How to use AppSetting string in switch statement

Tags: c#

How to achieve this same below with switch statement,

```
public static string GetPathWithPrefix(string path)
{
    string pathWithPrefox = string.Empty;
    if(path == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path1"])
    {
        pathWithPefix = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path1WithPrefix"];
    }
    else if(path == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path2"])
    {
        pathWithPefix = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path2WithPrefix"];
    }
    else if(path == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path3"])
    {
        pathWithPefix = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path3WithPrefix"];
    }
    return pathWithPefix;
}
```

I am getting compilation error when using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path1"]` in case of switch.

Comment: You cannot because you are evaluating different things. A `switch` statement is for when you are evaluating different conditions for the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch case in C# - a constant value is expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593377/switch-case-in-c-sharp-a-constant-value-is-expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Store the mapping in appropriate data structure

```
static readonly ImmutableDictionary<string, string> mapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "path1", "path1WithPrefix"},
    { "path2", "path2WithPrefix"},
    { "path3", "path3WithPrefix"},
}.ToImmutableDictionary();
```

2. Use the data structure with a simple lookup

```
public static string GetPathWithPrefix(string path)
{
    if (!mapping.ContainsKey(path))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Provided path is unknown");

    return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[mapping[path]];
}
```

Comment: Yeah it's good one (y)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create const variable for paths
and then you can use that veriable in switch case.

follow the example:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public const string path1 = "test1";// ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path1"];
    public const string path2 = "test2";// ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path2"];
    public const string path3 = "test3";// ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path3"];
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write(GetPathWithPrefix("test1"));
    }

    public static string GetPathWithPrefix(string path)
    {
            string pathWithPefix = string.Empty; 
            switch(path){
              case path1: 
                pathWithPefix = "t1";//ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path1WithPrefix"];
                break;
              case path2: 
                pathWithPefix = "t2";//ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path2WithPrefix"];
                break;
              case path3: 
                pathWithPefix = "t3";//ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path3WithPrefix"];
                break;
            }
         
            return pathWithPefix;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement is not the same thing as a big if-else statement.

Each case must be unique and evaluated statically. The switch statement does a constant time branch regardless of how many cases you have.

Please check this also.
[C# switch statement limitations - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905/c-sharp-switch-statement-limitations-why)