# any way to use variables in c# switch case?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I know that case cannot work with non-constant values, but what should I do if its impossible to make a constant? thats my case: we have three variables, need to find that, one that will correspond to the value of the switch condition, but how to do this if the case is not able to work with non-constants? are there any workarounds?

```
float value = 4;
float number1 = 3, number2 = 6, number3 = 4;

switch (value)
{
    case number1:
        {
             break;
        }
    case number2:
        {
             break;
        }
    case number3:
        {
             break;
        }
}
```

here is the oversimplified example, and yes, you can easily do this using if/else if, but what if the number of values will be 100? what to do in that case?

Comment: If you have 100 values, do you really have 100 variables too? That seems like a huge code smell to me. Better to have all the values in a list and loop over it, not to use a switch statement.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at answers from [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593377/switch-case-in-c-sharp-a-constant-value-is-expected)

Comment: Do watch out for floating popint comparison issues; decimal may be a better choice. Also : Depending on the actual actions a Disctionary<intOrDecimal, ActionOrDelegate) may be useful..

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use an inverted `Dictionary`, where the key is the value and the value the key.  Something like this:

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, int>();   

d.Add(3, 1);  
d.Add(6, 2);  
d.Add(4, 3);  

int keyPtr = d[value];  

switch (keyPtr):  
{  
    case 1:  
        //do something. 
        break;  
    case 2:  
        //do something else. 
        break;  
    case 3:  
        //do something different. 
        break;  
}
```

Obviously this is simplified, and I have used `int` not `float`, but the same applies to any type. Using this technique,
your n variables, become the first n items in the `Dictionary`. In practice at the very least, you should check if your given value exists as a key in the `Dictionary`. It should help you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to check whether your `value` variable equals to at least one of the variables `number1, number2, number3`, you could create an array of those numbers, say `numbers[]` and then create a method such as:

```
private bool checkValue(float value, float[] numbers) {

    foreach (float num in numbers) {
        if (num == value) return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

This solution fits any number of elements in your `numbers` array.
If you want you can also use a `List<float>` instead of an array, so you could dynamically add more and more elements (Without a fixed size).