# Why isn't my enum working in the switch statement?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, switch-statement

I remember using `enum`s in a `switch` statement in the past, and according to [C# how to use enum with switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136134/c-sharp-how-to-use-enum-with-switch) I am doing it the right way. But I've just tried to do it again and I received the following error:

> 'ApplicationMode' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'.

Here's the code I am using:

```
public static enum ApplicationMode
{
    Edit,
    Upload,
    Sync,
    None
}

private void edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(ApplicationMode) // This is where I see the error.
    {
        case ApplicationMode.Edit:
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Error message told the exact reason.

Comment: The switch statement expects you to supply a variable of type `ApplicationMode` rather than the type itself. That's why you're getting a compile error. You don't show a variable of type `ApplicationMode` in your program anywhere. Is there one set? More to the point, what are you trying to do? The user clicked the `Edit` button. Do you want to edit now, or do you want to set the mode to `Edit`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem 1:** enums are static by default so don't declare them as `static`.

**Solution 1:** you need to remove the `static` keyword in enum declaration

```
public enum ApplicationMode
{
    Edit,
    Upload,
    Sync,
    None
}
```

**Problem 2:** in `switch` case you need to provide the enum `ApplicationMode` variable which contains any valid enum value `[Edit,Upload,Sync,None]`, but you are trying to provide the `enum` type `ApplicationMode` itself.

**Solution 2:** provide the enum `ApplicationMode` variable which contains any valid value.

Try This:

```
ApplicationMode appMode = ApplicationMode.Upload; //assign any value
switch(appMode)
```

Comment: Thank you @Sudhakar, you just reminded me of how I used to do this. Your answer was very helpful.