# Clear way to write if statement

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
if (results.Contains(14))
{
    //anything
}
else if (results.Contains(15))
{
    //anything
}
else if (results.Contains(16))
{
    //anything
}
```

I want write this code with switch case :

```
switch (results)
{
    case results.Contains(14):
}
```

But we can't write this in C#.

What is the clear way for write the above code, knowing that `results` is a `long[]`?

Comment: What is the type of "results"? Is it derived from ICollection<int>, like List<int>?

Comment: switch statement requires a constant value.

Comment: @pylover yes i dont want just use switch.my question  is clear way to write

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ: Are you always display the same `exception`??

Comment: are you need to throw an exception for each item in result?

Comment: Why do you think that the original code is _unclear_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `switch` statement inside a `foreach`:

```
long[] results = new long[] { 15, 14, 16 };
foreach (long v in results)
{
    switch (v)
    {
        case 14:
            // anything
            break;
        case 15:
            // anything
            break;
        case 16:
            // anything
            break;
    }
}
```

And to better match with your question, you should order the array first and get out the foreach after a match:

```
long[] results = new long[] { 15, 14, 16 };
Array.Sort(results);
foreach (long v in results)
{
    switch (v)
    {
        case 14:
            // anything
            break;
        case 15:
            // anything
            break;
        case 16:
            // anything
            break;
        default:
            continue; // continue the foreach loop
    }
    break; // break the foreach loop because we had a valid match
}
```

Comment: Dictionaries are better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11617459/1714342

Comment: @wudzik: I think my answer better matches the (updated) question. The latter example in my answer is a drop in replacement for what the OP wants.

Comment: I like your answer, but it does not have to be a lambda expression. It could simply be: foreach (long v in array)
            {
                switch (v)
                {
                    case 14:
                        break;
                    case 15:
                        break;
                    case 16:
                        break;
                }
            }

Comment: @KaiHartmann you're right, it was overkill, removed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

What's wrong with this:

```
if (results.Contains(14) || results.Contains(15) || results.Contains(16))
{
  new Exception("anything");
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see the question was updated to throw an exception with the value that you're checking in the contains, which makes this answer not relevant anymore...

Comment: Please update your answer

Answer (score 4):

since it is probably in a string that has that number one solution would be to use a regular expression.

```
var m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(results, @"\d{1,2}")[0];
throw new Exception(m);
```

(NOTE: I did this in notepad so it might require a small tweak)

You will have to probably play with the match syntax as this is only good for 1-2 numbers. in a string.

Answer (score 4):

What are you really trying to do?

The following should work, but I am not sure if that's what you had in mind:

```
int[] values = {14, 15, 16};
foreach (var n in values) {
  if(result.Contains(n)) 
     throw new Exception(n.ToString()) 
}
```

-- EDIT: the question has changed considerably so here's an update --

I would probably use plain `if-else` but if you have many options or complex logic (e.g. not just `results.Contains()`), sometimes it is better to choose tables:

```
int[] results = {13, 14, 15};
action_map = new Dictionary<int, Action>();
action_map[14] = () => Console.Out.WriteLine("14");
action_map[15] = () => Console.Out.WriteLine("15");
action_map[16] = () => { throw new InvalidOperationException(); };
action_map[0] = () => {}; // NOP, default case - executed if no match found

var action_key = dict.Keys.FirstOrDefault(k => results.Contains(k));
action_map[action_key]();
```

In real code, I would probably wrap it into a class:

```
var table = new FnTable();
table.Add(14, () => Console.Out.WriteLine("14"));
table.Add(15, () => Console.Out.WriteLine("15"));
table.Add(16, () => { throw new InvalidOperationException(); });

int[] results = {13, 14, 15};
table.ExecuteFirstFrom(results);
```

Comment: I think you can remove the part 'if(result.Contains(n))', and use 'result' instead of 'values'.

Comment: Does not longer fit for the updated question

Comment: oh, thanks for the notification, I will fix it

Comment: @KaiHartmann that would affect the order of checks. they have to be done in order defined in `values` not `results`. if `results` is `{16, 15, 14}` then it wouldn't be the same

Answer (score 3):

I like approach with action dictionaries

```
        var swticher = new Dictionary<long, Func<Exception>>()
        {
            {15,()=>new Exception("15")},
            {14,()=>new Exception("14")}
        };

        throw swticher[14].Invoke();
```

Of course more complex examples will show power of this approach :)

Why to use dictionaries instead of switches: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11617459/1714342

Abstract:

> The short answer is that the switch statement executes linearly, while
>   the dictionary executes logarithmically.

Comment: Your quote is incorrect.  `switch`, in C#, can actually be implemented as a dictionary.  That's why all case statements must be compile time constants, rather than any executable expression.  Read the complete analysis of your own link for the details.

Answer (score 3):

Usually a **clear** way to replace if/switch statements is to use polymorphism. However, in the example you've provided the if statements are so trivial, that they can be replaced by a simple algorithm which calculates the contents of the exception, as stated in Robert Snyder's answer.

Answer (score 2):

[switch (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
Each case label specifies a constant value.
```

In your expected sample code, `results.Contains(14)` is not a constant value, so the syntax will not be valid.

Answer (score 2):

I would not actually recommend to do it this way, but if you're **really** into switch statements...

```
long? CheckSpecialNumbers(long[] res)
{
    var specialNumbers = new List<long>() {14, 15, 16};
    var inters= specialNumbers.Intersect(res);
    return inters.Count() > 0 ? (long?)inters.First() : null;
}
```

then you could do:

```
long? res = CheckSpecialNumbers(results);

switch (res)
{
    case 14:
        Console.WriteLine(14);
        break;
    case 15:
        Console.WriteLine(15);
        break;
    case 16:
        Console.WriteLine(16);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want write this code with switch case

A `switch`-`case` statement is used to branch the execution path according to *the value of a given variable*. The OP wants to branch according to *the value of a Boolean expression*, specifically, the return value of `Contains`. This can only be done using an `if`-`else` statement. Writing `switch (results)` doesn't make sense, since `results` is an array of integers.