# Parsing routine for over-sign characters relatively slow

Tags: c#, substring

I am trying to make the enclosed subroutine more performant using NET framework 4.6.1 although I will eventually port it to net core 2.2 .

It may run up to 250,000 times when parsing a file.

Using Visual Studio Performance Analyzer I see this routine seems to have a fairly high relative cost in the whole parsing process.

The code is part of a parsing program whose input is a binary file that contains some very old record formats that contain over-signed numbers.

**Over-signed Numbers (background)**

Instead of a minus sign and in order to save space the last digit is made a letter if the number is negative.  Its a very old standard dating back to when computers had limited memory and fixed width records were required for performance.

When parsing I need to convert the last letter back to a number and make the number negative

**Some examples of input and output of the routine**

00056K = -562

00032N = -325

**Current Code (slow)**

```
private int ConvertOverSign(string overSignedString)
{
    switch(overSignedString.Substring(overSignedString.Length -1,1))
    {
        case " ":
            return 0;
        case "J":
            return -Convert.ToInt32(overSignedString.Substring(0,overSignedString.Length -1) +  "1");
        case "K":
            return -Convert.ToInt32(overSignedString.Substring(0,overSignedString.Length -1) +  "2");
        case "L":
            return -Convert.ToInt32(overSignedString.Substring(0,overSignedString.Length -1) +  "3");
        case "M":
            return -Convert.ToInt32(overSignedString.Substring(0,overSignedString.Length -1) +  "4");
        case "N":
            return -Convert.ToInt32(overSignedString.Substring(0,overSignedString.Length -1) +  "5");
        case "O":
            return -Convert.ToInt32(overSignedString.Substring(0,overSignedString.Length -1) +  "6");
        case "P":
            return -Convert.ToInt32(overSignedString.Substring(0,overSignedString.Length -1) +  "7");
        case "Q":
            return -Convert.ToInt32(overSignedString.Substring(0,overSignedString.Length -1) +  "8");
        case "R":
            return -Convert.ToInt32(overSignedString.Substring(0,overSignedString.Length -1) +  "9");
        case "!":
            return -Convert.ToInt32(overSignedString.Substring(0,overSignedString.Length -1) + "0");
        default:
            return Convert.ToInt32(overSignedString);
    }
}
```

Comment: How slow is "slow"? Make sure you don't do micro-optimizations.

Comment: Your code would be shorter and more readable if you saved `overSignedString.Substring(0,overSignedString.Length -1)` to a variable instead of copy/pasting it in every case.  You'd reduce the length of your code by 500+ characters (each duplicate of that line is 56 characters long, and its duped 10 times).

Comment: What is the max number of digits for your fixed width values?

Comment: @BurnsBA on average the fields are about 6 to 10 chars wide

Comment: @Amy Wouldn't that do an allocation every time the function was called?

Comment: @mikes-so You're doing that anyway every time the function is called - twice.  The change I propose would not negatively hurt the efficiency of your code, but it would make it much shorter and more readable.  It's called refactoring.

Comment: Not for all case  the change you propose would substring even when not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure the below solution is fully equivalent to yours, but at least should give you a hint on how to make a very fast string-to-number parser.

```
    private int ConvertOverSign(string overSignedString)
    {
        if (overSignedString == " ") return 0;

        int value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < overSignedString.Length; i++)
        {
            char ch = overSignedString[i];
            switch (ch)
            {
                case '0':
                case '1':
                case '2':
                case '3':
                case '4':
                case '5':
                case '6':
                case '7':
                case '8':
                case '9':
                    value = value * 10 + (ch - 0x30);
                    break;

                case '!':
                    value *= 10;
                    return -value;

                case 'J':
                case 'K':
                case 'L':
                case 'M':
                case 'N':
                case 'O':
                case 'P':
                case 'Q':
                case 'R':
                    value = value * 10 + (ch - 'I');
                    return -value;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Bear in mind that string manipulations (e.g. Substring) are typically heavy if you need performance.

Comment: Great solution .  Need to return the value as negative when char is not a number.

Comment: Could you fix this for future searches please,  Return negative values for numbers that end in a letter.

Comment: should be correct now. Please, mark this answer as correct.

Comment: The maths is still incorrect for J-R as you are adding the value derived from the letter.  Easiest way is to keep your original calc and just return negative result `value = value * 10 + (ch - 'I');`   `return -value;` (note the minus sign)

Comment: Yes makes senseto use the same methodology for both.  Strangely this routine seems more CPU intensive than the others.  Currently Visual Studio allocation tracking is broken (known issue) but I am presuming this function would be the most GC friendly?

Comment: This code does not use GC at all: everything (data) are pushed on the stack. The only obvious exception is for the input string, but that's off the code context. If you want to compare your original version and this one, make an app with two loops, each for the code version. Same input, same loop count, just measure time of execution: GC will take longer to execute.

Answer (score 2):

Switch over the indexed character. `Substring` is actually alocating a new `string` and that is slow:

```
switch (overSignedString[Length - 1])
{
    case ' ':
        return 0;
    case "J":
        return ...
```

You might want to read [this](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int) to see if its worth parsing the string inside each case avoiding `Convert`. There are faster ways.

Comment: Using Indexed character increased the performance from 10 secs down to 7secs..  I also found out this routine potentially iterates over 3 million times .  Thank you so much.  Will look at the switch statements now.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is slow because it generates a lot of string garbage.

You could improve it by comparing characters instead of strings, and perform multiplication of the resulting integer instead of appending strings and using a lookup instead of a switch:

```
private Dictionary<char, int> _additions = new Dictionary<char, int>
{
    { '!', 0 },
    { 'J', 1 },
    { 'K', 2 },
    { 'L', 3 },
    { 'M', 4 },
    { 'N', 5 },
    { 'O', 6 },
    { 'P', 7 },
    { 'Q', 8 },
    { 'R', 9 },
};

private int ConvertOverSign(string overSignedString)
{
    var lastChar = overSignedString[overSignedString.Length -1];

    if (lastChar == ' ')
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (!_additions.TryGetValue(lastChar, out int addition))
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(overSignedString);
    }

    var result = (Convert.ToInt32(overSignedString.Substring(0, overSignedString.Length - 1)) * -10) - addition;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: valuable as solution, but dictionaries are heavier and slower than switch.

Comment: If that'd be the bottleneck now (can't really spin up a proper benchmark right now), then the OP could translate the dictionary lookup back into a switch.

Comment: I told you because I've tried once: a switch is basically a jump table, whereas a dictionary needs a lot of things more to resolve the proper case.

Comment: Before Roslyn, if the number of case statements is small, the compiler emits consecutive `if/else` statements.  If a large number of sequential cases, a dictionary is used.  Roslyn doesn't do this, AFAIK.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617091/in-a-switch-vs-dictionary-for-a-value-of-func-which-is-faster-and-why

Comment: @Amy many thanks for the clarification. Did not know the fallback for large sets of cases.